# Инструкция по Long Poll

Tags: long-poll

Ребят, где можно почитать подробно о Long Poll на русском языке? С примерами и т.д. Сколько искал, толкового так и не нашёл...

> Или кто может написать простенькое с
> помощью данной технологии:
>
> **Каждые 2 секунды получать с /check.php**
> **информацию.**

Comment: Да тут смысл весь с том, что клиент подключается к серверу и запрос как-бы "зависает на несколько секунд". А скрипт на сервере в своё время ожидает какого-то события (допустим новое значение в БД). Если это событие происходит, то скрипт на сервере отдает сообщение и прекращает свою работу. Клиент получает сообщение и вновь создает подключение к серверному скрипту.

Comment: @lampa, мне бы пример кода.. А то у меня тупо стоит setInterval($.get('...', function(data) {...})}, 2000); Так же сайт взорвётся. Правильно?

Comment: К сожалению, пример есть только дома. Дома буду поздно. Но скинуть - скину.

Comment: @lampa, я буду ждать :))

Comment: @lampa, нашёл вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/111253/blog941.html. Это то? Протестил, вроде всё ок. С задержкой в 2 секунды выводит.

Comment: @ModaL да, то.

Comment: @lampa, и что, нагрузки будет меньше создавать?

Comment: @ModaL раз придумали такой способ, то логично, что да - меньше.

Comment: Существует мнение, что скорее стоит почитать о Websockets, которые являются альтернативой.

Comment: Лучше забудьте про эту технологию, мой знакомый лишился премии из-за нее  =) смотрите лучше в сторону сокетов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long-pulling aka comet
```

Позволяет получать клиенту данные в момент появления их на сервере, в отличии от периодических опросов сервера через заданный интервал.

Фактически - это обычный http запрос, на который сервер ответит не сразу, а когда появятся данные.

В пуллинге не совсем корректно говорить об интервале запросов, потому как в момент получения ответа клиентом http запрос завершается и клиент сразу делает следующий запрос (не делая никаких пауз).

Но к примеру `http-bind (bosh)` для `xmpp` в начале установления сессии указывает время, через которое сервер при отсутствии данных сам разорвет соединение.

На мой взгляд, проще всего написать пример на стороне сервера используя nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Ну если нужно только вот это -

> Каждые 2 секунды получать с /check.php информацию.

То как-то так:

```
var answer=[];  
setInterval( function() {
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "check.php", data:"", 
    dataType:"text", timeout:30000, async:false,
      success: function(data) {
          // делаем что-нить с ответом сервера, например пишем в массив
          answer.push(data);
      },
      error: function(err, err_txt) {
            answer.push("ERROR");
            console.log("ERROR RECIVE DATA: "+err_txt);
      }
    });
}, 2000);
```

Но тут кроется неприятность - мы не можем гарантировать, что ответ от первого запроса придет раньше, чем пройдут 2 секунды, после который пойдет следующий запрос, поэтому есть риск наплодить кучу висяков-запросов, бесцельно отжирающих ресурсы.
Лично я для борьбы с этим использую `setTimeout`, последовательно запускаемый по окончании успешного или неуспешного запроса.