# Чат на ExtJS для сайта [закрыт]

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, extjs, php

Здравствуйте!
Я новичок в ExtJS...
Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность сделать чат на ExtJS для сайта?
Меня интересует связка ExjtJS, PHP, MySQL.
Возможно есть примеры или поднятые темы... сам честно искал, но увы...

Идея простая - форма в каком-нибудь углу экрана с возможностью отправки сообщений и отображения чужих сообщений (в реальном времени, не по таймеру).

Comment: Библиотека ExtJS более склонна к созданию интерфейсов, потому широко используется для реализации интерфейса панели администрирования (админки) в различных CMS(F). Эх..., если бы она не была такой тяжелой. 

Вы уверены в своём выборе, что именно этот инструмент Вам подходит? Впрочем, знать полезно, но, ИМХО, только в рамках работы с какой-нибудь CMS-кой, а именно, административной её частью

Comment: Для чата лучше использовать Node.js на стороне сервера. На клиенте можно и ExtJS, но мне кажется это можно и ручками написать. ExtJS это довольно сложная библиотека.

Comment: Собственно нужен чат для пользователя - на сайт, и в админку - для меня. Админка как раз таки на ExtJS (пока в разработке). Потому и думал делать их в чем-то одном.

Comment: @GuRuZ Повторюсь, я бы отказался от ExtJS в своём проекте в пользу иных библиотек. Я смотрю, Вам стали приводить ответы не по теме. Вам ведь надо, если не пример, то хотя бы направление куда двигаться - как с помощью функционала ExtJS, реализовать поставленную задачу, если я всё правильно понял.

А так, если необходима общая картина, то я уже отвечал:


[2-х секундное обращение к БД][1]

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/170836/php-2-%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B4

Comment: @romeo ответ содержит описание работы чата, не надо тут!) Да плюс человек начинает не с того, extjs предназначен для более масштабных проектов, но никак не должен служить формочкой в уголке.

Comment: @lampa Не буду тут:) Всё верно, каждый из вас привёл пример с использованием различных инструментов без использования ExtJS (но мы дали понять, что ExtJS сложна и тяжела для реализации чат-формочки в уголке).

Тот же Node.js не всегда возможно использовать (привет хостингу на LAMP).

Думаю, @GuRuZ будет интересно узнать про разные инструменты и методы (Polling, Long Poll, WebSocket), которые помогут ему в реализации поставленной задачи (чата).

Comment: Ок, понял что собрался стрелять из пушки по комарам...  
Спасибо за разъяснения!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как пример, форма диалога Вконтакте.

Сама форма ничем не выделяется. Это обычный блок с абсолютным позиционированием и эффектом drag & drop. Сам способ реализации чата можно подглядеть тут: [Инструкция по Long Poll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175548/long-poll-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-long-poll)